# How to query database column names?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table with multiple columns starting with one keyword `link_`. I.E. `link_0_10`, `link_10_20`, `link_20_30` and so on.

I want to select only columns starting with these `link_` keywords. How to do that? I can query by RegEx on the value, but on the columns? I have not been able to.

**P.S.:** I have no prior idea of how many columns may be present.

Comment: That is a very bad database design, that should be fixed.

Comment: What you ask for requires dynamic SQL, which is more complex that a regular query. Basically, your question indicates a design problem. You should be storing each column on a separate row, with a column that stores the values (link_0_10, link_10_20, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change database name and table name with yours and run this query

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database_name' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='table_name' and  COLUMN_NAME like 'link_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'mytable' and column_name like 'link_%'
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.